# Clone Github repository, installing packages with NPM or both?

Tags: node.js, api, github, npm, airtable

I want to use the API for [Airtable](https://airtable.com/) and they have a [Javascript API client at Gitbub](https://github.com/Airtable/airtable.js). I have installed Node.js/NPM and Git but I'm not sure what to do to get started (I know Javascript, that's not the problem).

This is what I have tried:

**Following the instructions**

I have tried to just run `npm install airtable` (in Git Bash) like it says. That installs a file called *package-lock.json* and a folder called *node_modules*, containing 71 packages/sub folders. I'm pretty sure thats not sufficient to start coding and implementing the API.

**Cloning the repo**

I have also tried cloning the repository. The package file lists three available scripts:

- "pretest": "npm run lint",
- "lint": "grunt jshint"
- "test": "jest --env node"

I have only used `npm run dev` before but that's is obviously not an option here so I am totally lost. I have watched several tutorials on how to use Github and to NPM but they didn't help in this case. What am I supposed to do to get started?

Thanks!

Comment: `I'm pretty sure thats not sufficient to start coding and implementing the API.` that's where you're wrong. Add a JavaScript file to your project and add the line `const Airtable = require('airtable');`. You now have access to the API.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what does it mean that I have access to the API? What am I supposed to do after I have added the js-file and declared/imported Airtable?

Comment: I had missed a big part of Airtables API documentation. Thank you!